# How to run doctrine migrations from the php code?

Tags: php, doctrine, migration

I am trying to integrate database migrations into my project. My project is a plugin for a php framework which is powered by the plugins (each plugin have its own migration scripts). Usually (or always ...) these migration scripts are represented as  .sql scripts. Framework applies these scripts during installation/deinstallation process.

So, I want to use another way of applying migrations in the my plugin: `doctrine-migrations`.

Because of execution of migrations are called by the framework from the code, I want to call doctrine also from the code. But ... there is no tutorial how to do it: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/

How to call doctrine migrations from the php code with a MINIMAL configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I use Doctrine Migrations (2.2.0) for some Wordpress Plugins and call them from the code like follows:

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Configuration\Configuration;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Helper\ConfigurationHelper;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\BufferedOutput;

$connection = DriverManager::getConnection([
    'dbname' => 'migrations_docs_example',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
]);

$configuration = new Configuration($connection);
$configuration->setName('My Doctrine Migrations');
$configuration->setMigrationsDirectory(__DIR__ . '/database/migrations');
$configuration->setMigrationsNamespace('database\migrations');
$configuration->setMigrationsTableName('doctrine_migration_versions');

$helperSet = new HelperSet();
$helperSet->set(new ConnectionHelper($connection), 'db');
$helperSet->set(new ConfigurationHelper($connection, $configuration));

$command = new MigrateCommand();
$command->setHelperSet($helperSet);

$input = new ArrayInput([]);
$input->setInteractive(false);

$output = new BufferedOutput();

$exitcode = $command->run($input, $output);
if ($exitcode > 0) {
    throw new Exception($output->fetch());
}
```

Now, the migration throws exceptions if something goes terribly wrong, so wrapping it in a try-catch block is probably wise.